# How can I add new key with id in array javascript?

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, key

I try like this :

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var club = [
        {id:123, name:'chelsea'},
        {id:456, name:'mu'},
        {id:789, name:'liverpool'}
    ];

    var newClub = club.map(function(element){
       element.original = true;
       element.kw = false;
       return element;
    });

    console.log(newClub);
</script>
```

It works. But I want the key original and kw with id like this :

```
var club = [
    {id:123, name:'chelsea', original123:true, kw123:false},
    {id:456, name:'mu', original456:true, kw456:false},
    {id:789, name:'liverpool', original789:true, kw789:false}
];
```

How can I do it?

Comment: `element['kw' + element.id] = false` (same for the other one)

Comment: On another note, this is a very weird thing to want to do.

Comment: I'm not sure if you really want that...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For **dynamic properties**, you need to use bracket notation. For reference, [Property accessors](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_accessors). Try following

```js
var club = [{id: 123,name: 'chelsea'},{id: 456,name: 'mu'},{id: 789,name: 'liverpool'}];

var newClub = club.map(function(element) {
  element['original' + element.id] = true;
  element['kw' + element.id] = false;
  return element;
});

console.log(newClub);
```

You can also simplify your code like following

```js
var club = [{id: 123,name: 'chelsea'},{id: 456,name: 'mu'},{id: 789,name: 'liverpool'}];

let newClub = club.map(o => ({...o, [`original${o.id}`] : true, [`kw${o.id}`] : false}));
console.log(newClub);
```

Answer (score 5):

You should use dynamic properties:

```
var newClub = club.map(function(element) {
  element['original' + element.id] = true;
  element['kw' + element.id] = false;
  return element;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use template literals to create dynamic property names.

```js
var club = [
  {id:123, name:'chelsea'},
  {id:456, name:'mu'},
  {id:789, name:'liverpool'}
];

var result = club.map(({id,...rest}) => ({
  ...rest,
  [`original${id}`]: true,
  [`kw${id}`]: false
}))

console.log(result)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `.map()` and `Object.assign()` methods:

```js
var data = [
    {id:123, name:'chelsea'},
    {id:456, name:'mu'},
    {id:789, name:'liverpool'}
];

var result = data.map(o => Object.assign({}, o, {
    ['original' + o.id]: true,
    ['kw' + o.id]: false
}));

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```